# Derived push-forward and pull back.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

All functors are derived and all categories are bounded derived categories of coherent sheaves. Suppose that we have got an inclusion of a smooth divisor $j:D\rightarrow X$ in a smooth projective variety. Is it true that $$j^*j_*F=F\otimes j^*j_*O_D?$$

Comment: I should add a few remarks:
1) This is not the well known $j_*j^*F=F\otimes j_* O_D$
2) If it is not well known it is probably wrong, but
there is always a triangle:
$F\otimes O_D(-D)[1]\rightarrow j^*j_*F \rightarrow F$ by
Bondal, Orlov "Semiort. decomp." Lemma 3.3
3) We can calculate RHS by restricting and tensoring the resolution 
$0\rightarrow O(-D)\rightarrow O\rightarrow j_*O_D\rightarrow 0$
As, after restricting to $D$ the map is zero, we see that RHS is a sum of $F$ and $F\otimes O_D(-D)[1]$. In particular it fits to the previous triangle (that maybe does not split).

Comment: 4) If $F$ is an injective coherent sheaf then LHS and RHS fit into the triangle:
$(LvR)HS\rightarrow F\rightarrow F\otimes O_D(-D)[2]$
with the last morphism being zero, as these are injective sheaves in diffrent shifts. 

5)There is a morphism from LHS to RHS induced by a morphism from $j_* F$ to $j_*(F\otimes j^*j_*O_D)=j_*F\otimes j_*O_D$, that comes from $O_X\rightarrow j_*O_D$.



Comment: 6) It is true on the (not nec. full) subcategory $j^*(D(X))$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no. The simplest example that I know is $X = P^3$, $D = P^1\times P^1$, $F = O(0,1)$. In this case $j^*j_*O_D = O_D \oplus O_D(-2)[1]$ and hence $F\otimes j^*j_*O_D = F \oplus F(-2)[1]$, while $j^*j_*F$ fits into a triangle
$$
F(-2)[1] \to j^*j_*F \to F
$$
which is not split. To see this note that $j_*F$ has a resolution of the form 
$$
0 \to O_X(-1)^2 \to O_X^2 \to j_*F \to 0,
$$
which gives a distinguished triangle
$$
O_D(-1,-1)^2 \to O_D^2 \to j^*j_*F.
$$
It follows easily from this that $Hom(F,j^*j_*F) = 0$, which shows that $F$ is not a direct summand of $j^*j_*F$.